# React native not showing video in FlatList

Tags: react-native, expo

So I have made a FlatList and I want to display a video in it. But when I try rendering it in the list it is not showing. But when I put the code to display the video outside the FlatList it's working fine.

This is my FlatList:

```
// the array that I am using (just for testing)
const array = [1, 2]

<FlatList style={{flex: 1}} keyExtractor={item => item} data={array} renderItem={({item}) => <VideoItem/>}/>
```

This is the item I am rendering (If I place the `View` that I return outside the FlatList it's working fine)

```
function VideoItem () {
        return(
            <View
                style={{height: 500}}
            >
                <Video
                    style={[
                        {width: width, height: "100%"},
                        {borderWidth: 1, borderColor: colors.yellow, borderRadius: 10}
                    ]}
                    ref={video}
                    source={{uri: mediaArray[1]}}
                    useNativeControls
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={setStatus}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display video thumbnails in flat list
use **react-native-create-thumbnail** package

```
    import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import { measures, colors } from '../values';
import { createThumbnail } from "react-native-create-thumbnail";
import { GradientCircularProgress } from "react-native-circular-gradient-progress";
import PlayIcon from '../assest/PlayIcon.svg'
import FastImageView from '../components/FastImageView'

class VideoThumbnail extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            thumbnailUrl: null
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.generateThumbnail()
    }

    generateThumbnail() {
        const { videoUrl } = this.props
        createThumbnail({
            url: videoUrl,
            timeStamp: 1000,
        }).then(res => {
            this.setState({
                thumbnailUrl: res.path
            })
        });

    }

    render() {
        const { properties, mainItem, height, width } = this.props;
        const { thumbnailUrl } = this.state
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <FastImageView
                    style={{
                        height: height,
                        width: width,
                    }}
                    source={{ uri: thumbnailUrl }}
                />
                <View style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
                    <PlayIcon />
                </View>
                {properties.addChatAttachment && properties.addChatAttachment.progress != 100 && mainItem._id == 1 &&
                    <View style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: colors.popupbg,
                        height: height,
                        width: width,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <GradientCircularProgress
                            size={measures.fontSize * 5}
                            progress={properties.addChatAttachment.progress}
                            strokeWidth={2}
                            emptyColor={'#F2EFEF'}
                            startColor={colors.appcolor}
                            endColor={colors.appcolor}
                            middleColor={colors.appcolor}
                        />
                    </View>
                }

            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalParent: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: colors.white
    },
    filename: {
        width: '70%',
        fontSize: measures.fontSize / 1.2,
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
        color: colors.appcolor
    },
    modal: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        height: measures.height / 1.05,
        width: '100%',
    },
    headerView: {
        width: '100%',
        height: measures.fontSize * 3,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: measures.fontSize,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },

})
export default VideoThumbnail;
```

Use the VideoThumbnail component in flat list item like

```
function VideoItem () {
        return(

     <VideoThumbnail
     videoUrl={mediaArray[1]}
     properties={props}
     mainItem={item}
     height={measures.fontSize * 10}
     width={measures.width / 1.8}
     />
        )
    }
```

Comment: I want to display a video in a flatlist not a thumbnail